# $F(x)=m(A\cap(-\infty,x))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is measurable with finite Lebesgue measure and $F(x)=m(A\cap(-\infty,x))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then prove that $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I actually am quite lost here. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For any increasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\rightarrow x $ we have
$$
|F(x_n)-F(x)|=|m(A\cap(x_n,x))|\leq |x_n-x|\rightarrow 0
$$
and so $F(x_n)\rightarrow F(x)$, proving continuity.

Comment: Where does this sequence of $x_n$ come from? I don't see how this is equivalent?

Comment: The definition of a continuous function is that for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then the sequence $F(x_n)$ converges to $F(x)$. It's easy to see how this works for any sequnce $(x_n)$ where $x_i > x, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. a decreasing sequence, so he should how it also works for any increasing sequence. @YaG